# Sending oozie job output to mail ID

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, oozie, oozie-coordinator, bigdata

I have few commands like in hadoop that needs to be executed everyday and the result needs to be sent to my mail ID. How can I do this using oozie JOB?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Oozie Coordinator that you can submit workflows based on time and data triggers. You can an find an example below for a daily coordinator job of sending emails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coordinator-app name="cord1" frequency="${coord:days(1)}"
             start="${jobStart}" end="${jobEnd}"
             timezone="UTC"
             xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4">
  <action name="an-email">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
            <to>bob@initech.com,the.other.bob@initech.com</to>
            <cc>will@initech.com</cc>
            <subject>Email notifications for ${wf:id()}</subject>
            <body>The wf ${wf:id()} successfully completed.</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="myotherjob"/>
        <error to="errorcleanup"/>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Other frequency you can set is following below:

```
${coord:minutes(int n)}
${coord:hours(int n)}
${coord:days(int n)}
${coord:months(int n)}
```

Comment: Mobin is it possible to mail the output data of the command to mail in body>The wf ${wf:id()} successfully completed.</body> I am executing a command hadoop fs -ls / and I want the output list of directories into my mail.

Comment: @Naveen Running hdfs commands is another workflow. We cannot have two workflows in Coordinator at the same time. But you can use Oozie Bundle to have multiple workflows that occur every day. One is HDFS command workflow and two is email workflow. Keep in mind that dependency between jobs need to be managed by user.

Answer (score 0):

Following things are to be set up for doing a mapred action and sending email after that. In your oozie-site.xml, Add the below settings and restart oozie. Replace values with the same specific to your environment.

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.email.smtp.host</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.email.smtp.port</name>
    <value>25</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.email.from.address</name>
<value></value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.email.smtp.auth</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.email.smtp.username</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.email.smtp.password</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
```

In your workflow.xml, add the below instructions with your environment settings. This includes the email triggering action once the mapreduce is completed.

```
<workflow-app name="WorkFlowJavaMapReduceAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="mapReduceAction" />
<action name="mapReduceAction">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${outputDir}" />
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
                <value></value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                <value></value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.mapoutput.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.key.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.Text</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.value.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                <value>${inputDir}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                <value>${outputDir}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.acl-view-job</name>
                <value>*</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.acl-view-job</name>
                <value>*</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.libpath</name>
                <value>${appPath}/lib</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="emailCommands" />
    <error to="killJob" />
</action>

<action name="emailCommands">
    <fs>
        <mkdir path='${makeDirectoryAbsPath}' />
        <move source='${dataInputDirectoryAbsPath}' target='${dataDestinationDirectoryRelativePath}' />
    </fs>
    <ok to="sendEmailSuccess" />
    <error to="sendEmailKill" />
</action>
<action name="sendEmailSuccess">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${emailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Status of workflow ${wf:id()}</subject>
        <body>The workflow ${wf:id()} completed successfully</body>
    </email>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="end" />
</action>
<action name="sendEmailKill">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${emailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Status of workflow ${wf:id()}</subject>
        <body>The workflow ${wf:id()} had issues and was killed. The error
            message is: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}</body>
    </email>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="killJob" />
</action>

<kill name="killJob">
    <message>"Killed job due to error:
        ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" />    
</workflow-app>
```

Please refer this blogpost http://webthanga.blogspot.in/2016/01/oozie-map-reduce-action-with-send-mail.html